# DTUTIL command to export all DTS packages to File system from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, dts

I'm searching for dtutil command to export all legacy DTS packages from SQL Server to file system. I'm aware we can use dtutil to export SSIS packages but help me with DTS! If we cannot do that via dtutil is there any way we could do that?

Comment: The DTS Packages are stored in a SQL Server 2000? 2005 had no DTS support afaik!?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft recommends the use of this tool, give it a try:
http://www.sqldts.com/242.aspx

Comment: it's sql 2005. Any means without using any tools?